Can this Binary Search Tree be optimal with $x$ expected comparisons?
I was given this 
Binary Search Tree. The question asks whether this tree can ever be optimal with $2.1$ expected comparisons, and I am completely lost on how to even approach this problem. Trying to construct weights for which this works seems impossible, but I also don't know how I would go about disproving the statement.

Suppose the probality of each element being searched by the node label itself is denoted by the node label itself. Then the expected cost is given by:
$1\times A + 2\times B + 3\times D + 4\times (C+E) = 2.1$ (given)
Also, we have $A+B+D+C+E = 1$ (probabilities)
From these two, we get $1\times B + 2\times D + 3\times (C+E) = 1.1$
In order to make this tree optimal, the search frequencies must follow the following inequalities:
$A \ge B+D+C+E$ [implies $A$ must be at least $0.5$]
$B \ge D+C+E$ [implies $B$ must be at least $0.25$]
$D \ge C$ and
$D \ge E$
This will give us $A+B+2D \ge 1.1$, which gives $D \ge C+E+0.1$. This, together with the above inequalities, somewhat forces your hand.
Since, $A\ge 0.5, B\ge 0.25$ we have $D+C+E\le 0.25$. This give us $0\le C+E\le 0.075$ and $0.175 \le D \le 0.25$. Thus maximum value $1\times A + 2\times B + 3\times D + 4\times (C+E)$ can get is $1\times 0.5 + 2\times 0.25 + 3\times 0.175 + 4\times 0.075 = 1.825 \le 2.1 ~~~~\square$
